# ADF user property "New" button disabled

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

[image]

In My ADF pipeline  I have some activities that I can add user properties. But the one I have shown above(which is inside a foreach activity, cannot be added. I could delete it. Is there a limit for user properties? I do not want to delete one and try just incase I cannot add them again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a limit of 5 user properties